# Refactoring Vue Method using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, refactoring, lodash

I have some logic in the `watch` prop in one of my Vue component's that switches between elements in sequential order upon press the down arrow key (key code 40). Its not total clutter **at the moment**  however longterm it will become extremely inefficient. Heres the structure:

```
data () {
 return {
  firstElActive: true,
  secondElActive: false,
  thirdElActive: false
  ...
 }

},

props: {
 nextEl: {
  type: Boolean,
  default: false,
  required: true
 }
},

watch: {
 nextEl: function (value) {
  if (this.nextEl) {
   if (this.firstElActive) {
    this.firstElActive = !this.firstElActive;
    this.secondElActive = !this.secondElActive;
    ... // other specific logic
   }
   else if (this.secondElActive) {
    this.secondElActive = !this.secondElActive;
    this.thirdElActive = !this.thirdElActive;
    ... // other specific logic
   }
   ... // so forth
  }
 }
}
```

As you can probably assess, this will get pretty bad, pretty quick. I have **Lodash** bootstrapped globally (`window._ = require('lodash')`), and would like to utilize it... I'm just in a quandary as to which method(s) will refactor this most efficiently. Suggestions?

Comment: So your `nextEl` boolean will be toggling `false`/`true` and every time it goes `true` you want to "move forward" the active el?

Comment: Typically you just set an `activeElement` and hide/show based on that. When your key is pressed, all you would do is determine which element is active next and set it. Then it's trivial to handle any number of elements. lodash is really not necessary.

Comment: Here is a quickie example that needs some work but gives the gist. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/bLPBEb?editors=1010

Comment: right, however what if i wanted to do specific logic before each increment of activeElement depending on its value? @Bert

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Do whatever you want before setting the `activeElement` in onKeyDown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using many boolean data properties use an active index. Increment or decrement this active index while going up or down.

```js
new Vue({
  name: 'example',

  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: 0, value: 'item 1'}, 
        { id: 1, value: 'item 2'}, 
        { id: 2, value: 'item 3'},
      ],
      activeIndex: 0,
      arrowUpKeyCode: 38,
      arrowDownKeyCode: 40,
    };
  },

  computed: {
    currentItem() {
      return this.items[this.activeIndex];
    },
  },

  methods: {
    bindEvents() {
      document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
    },

    unbindEvents() {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
    },

    onPrev() {
      console.log(`on prev (key code ${this.arrowUpKeyCode}) ${this.currentItem.value}`);
    },

    onNext() {
      console.log(`on next (key code ${this.arrowDownKeyCode}) ${this.currentItem.value}`);
    },

    goPrev() {
      if (this.activeIndex > 0) {
        this.activeIndex -= 1;
        this.onPrev();
      }
    },

    goNext() {
      if (this.activeIndex < this.items.length - 1) {
        this.activeIndex += 1;
        this.onNext();
      }
    },

    onKeyDown(ev) {
      if (this.arrowUpKeyCode === ev.keyCode) this.goPrev();
      else if (this.arrowDownKeyCode === ev.keyCode) this.goNext();
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    this.unbindEvents();
  },
}).$mount('#example');
```

```css
.active { background-color: dodgerblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in items" 
        :key="item.id" 
        :class="{ active: index === activeIndex }">
      {{ item.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `$emit` get sent to the parent of the component? what if i wanted to specific logic stemming from the component itself?

Comment: Since I saw you used props I mistakenly supposed you wanted to communicate with a parent component, if that's not the case you can just call another method from the component itself. I will update my answer.

Comment: one more thing! what if i don't want to show all items at once, only if its active or the `activeIndex === item.id` ?

Comment: Use the `v-if` directive like so: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3uqt9nL0/)

Comment: You can use the `currentItem` computed property instead of using `v-for` as well: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/baah34z9/).

Comment: great alternatives!